# The appropriate way to analyse survival data when each time point constitutes a random sample from the population

Tags: survival

We have an infection dataset where individuals have been treated (or not) with a chemical and then were followed them over time to see whether they picked up infections in the wild at different rates.

Because in this species the detection of infection requires destructive sampling, at each time point the individuals we know the "survival" status of are a random sample of those individuals in the population, so we have an estimate of the position of the population survival curve at each time point.

Is there are systematic way to analyse this data using survival analysis tools, to both look for a difference in infection rate caused by the drug while controlling for the effect of other covariates? I've always understood that the standard  methods require individuals to be explicitly followed through time rather than the population to be implicitly followed, though that could well be wrong.